# Smartgwt selectitem key value issue

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I have a `SelectItem` which I fill through a `Map` that has  this combo is within a listgridfield, so good up there, but when I select any item in the combobox instead of get the description or value of the map puts the key in the listgridfield.

How I can do to make me set the value instead of key? now I tried to do with AddChangeHandler but has not worked.

I got the next code:

```
final ListGridField measureField = new ListGridField(CdmsConstants.MEASURE_ABB,    CdmsConstants.CMB_MEASURE_TITULO, 100);

final SelectItem measureComboBox = new SelectItem();
measureComboBox.setDefaultToFirstOption(false);
measureComboBox.setName(CdmsConstants.MEASURE_ABB);
measureComboBox.setTitle(CdmsConstants.CMB_MEASURE_TITULO);
measureComboBox.setDefaultValues(CdmsConstants.CMB_DEFAULT_VALUE);
measureComboBox.setType("comboBox");
measureComboBox.setVisible(true);
measureComboBox.setValueMap(result);
measureComboBox.setValidateOnExit(true);

measureField.setEditorType(measureComboBox);
```

In the measureComboBox When i put the variable result (that is a Map) and click to any item of the combo the value that shows into the combo box is the key of the linckedhashmap and no the value of the item... how can i make to change this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't even understand your question...

Comment: i already edit my question, thanks a lot 4 ur help.

Comment: Do you really have to mess with the ListGrid editor?
why not have the 2 objects visible side by side and trigger the add on the listgrid on selectionChanged in the SelectItem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a datasource instead of `LinkedHashMap`, then you can use `setValueField` method of `SelectItem` instance. but in this case MAY you can use `setValueFormatter` method of your `SelectItem` object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar problem, my solution that can be seen here [ListGrid.setEditorCustomizer in SmartGWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046287/listgrid-seteditorcustomizer-in-smartgwt) was to use a datasource for the `SelectItem` and then implemented my own `CellFormatter`