# ListGrid.setEditorCustomizer in SmartGWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smartgwt selectitem key value issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492319/smartgwt-selectitem-key-value-issue)

I'm using setEditorCustomizer to set custom editors for some fields in a ListGrid, my specific problem is on a SelectItem

Something like this:

```
grid.setEditorCustomizer(new ListGridEditorCustomizer() {
    public FormItem getEditor(ListGridEditorContext context) {
         SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem();
         LinkedHashMap<String, String> valuesMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
         valuesMap.put("0","some text");
         valuesMap.put("1","other text");
         selectItem.setValueMap(valuesMap);
    }
}
```

Note that I'm not creating select items for every row.

Everything works great when editing the row, I see "some text" and "other text" in the dropdown but when I'm not editing the value I see the corresponding key instead of the value.

I have searched the javadoc but couldn't find anything, if anything is not explicit please ask and I will add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding a solution with a `DataSource` and setting it in the optionDataSource of the `SelectItem` and setting displayField and valueField to the respective fields.

And then for when the field is not being edited, in the `ListGridField` I set a custom `CellFormatter` that returned the proper data (this involves returning proper data for the other values too).

I'm pretty sure there may be a simpler way, but this way it works for me so I will leave it like that for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setValueMap() on the ListGridField where the SelectItem appears as well (with the same valueMap).

Comment: Tried it, but still got the keys instead.